# How do I defeat the Wooden Shield Moblin?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After completing my first trial, I quickly encountered my first Wooden Shield Moblin:

[image: Wooden Shielf Moblin]

I'm able to hack away at his shield, but can't seem to kill him.  It looks (and sounds) like my blows continually bounce off his big, fat belly.  **How do I defeat this guy?**  Fi is no help at all.

Comment: Why has no-one said shield bash?

Comment: Shield bash is so useful for so many enemies. But I'd suggest just dashing up the enemy's shield and hitting him from behind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried dashing at the shield (thus vaulting over it) and attacking his backside?

Bombs and arrows also work too.

Comment: This, as long as you don't cut it any, you can vault over him like one with a metal shield.

Answer (score 2):

I found that there are three variations of killing him that I enjoy.. they can be intermixed for whatever the situation allows.

First, you definitely want to get rid of his shield.. this can be done in one of two ways:

1) You can slice horizontally and vertically on his wooden shield, and eventually after you get it to about a quarter of its size, he will toss it away. This makes his soft, squishy belly vulnerable for attack.

2) You can chuck a bomb at him, and he will back away while holding the shield as up protection.. The bomb should blow his shield up if tossed correctly.

From here, you have a few options, but here are a couple of my favorites:

1) You can slash his belly or rear section a ton of times, and he should go down. Watch out for his attacks while you are doing this, as he will be trying to approach and hit you in the process. If he starts rearing back to attack you with the spear, do a shield bash right before/when he starts his attack and it will knock him off kilter. This should allow you to slash away some more at his soft, squishy belly. I enjoy this because it has a more personal feel to it, it's more exciting, and it reminds me of jello. It should be noted, when you are slashing his butt/belly, it may look like he is not getting hurt.. He is though, it just takes a lot of hits.

2) You can blow him up with a bomb. He backs away very slowly, so if you roll it/throw one or two just right, it will kill him. Also enjoyable, but more from a popcorn theatre point of view. I opt for the first method though, as I tend to be pretty stingy with my bombs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that I have discovered so far - you can either hack away at his shield until only a small bit of it is left, at which time he will toss it aside, or you can dash up and over his shield and whack away at his backside.

Careful - the shield-hacking technique only works on the first appearance of these guys. Later on, there will be versions of them with reinforced shields, at which time you have to get creative!

Comment: And by creative, you mean do the other method.  ;)

Comment: Haha, yes, of course - unless you have room to snipe them from afar. Easily my favorite way of taking them out, even if it does take quite a few arrows!

Answer (score 1):

If you are good at it just shield bash his spear attacks and go to town on him. they go down easy that way.

also as mentioned bow and arrows work very well as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, it will take a LOT of slashes to kill this guy.  You can in some cases stun him a slingshot pellet aimed at his head, that'll give you a pretty big head start on the hacking of his gut.

Later on, it takes about 3-4 fully-charged arrows to his head to down him.  I'm not sure how many bombs it takes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other answers (vault off the shield, hack like crazy), I've also found that these guys have a particular fear of bombs.  Roll one over nearby and they will step lightly with a careful tiptoe animation.  This essentially stuns then well enough that you can get in a bunch of hits.